# Continuous selectors of a continuous multifunctin on a compact metric space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, gn.general-topology

I am currently working on a continuous selector problem of multifunctions. I am trying to figure out if a continuous multifunction defined on a compact metric space always admit a continuous selector.

A mapping $\phi$ from a topological space $X$ to the family of subsets of a topological space $Y$ is called *multifunction*. It is *upper hemicontinuous* if the set $\{ x \in X : \phi (x) \subset U \}$ is open in $X$ for every open set of $Y$. It is *lower hemicontinuous* if $ \{ x \in X : \phi (x) \cap U \not = \emptyset \}$ is open in $X$ for every open set of $Y$. It is *continuous* if it is upper and lower hemicontinuous. A function $f: X \to Y$ is a continuous selector of $\phi$ if $f$ is continuous and $f(x) \in \phi(x)$ for all $x \in X.$

Do you know of any examples of continuous multifunctions defined on a compact metric space that do not have a continuous selection?

I know the following Michael selection theorem:

A lower hemicontinuous multifunction with nonempty and convex values from a paracompact space into a completely metrizable locally convex space admits a continuous selector.

I am wondering if it is possible that a continuous multifunction does not have a continuous selector if the multifunction is not convex-valued.

I would greatly appreciate insights or suggestions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X = Y = \mathbb{S}^1$.

Take $f(\theta) = \{ \theta / 2, \theta/2 + \pi\}$.